# how to display a piechart in android by retrieving data from the given database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my android application I have inserted data into database using one activity. In another activity I want to retrieve data from database and generate a pie chart using this data. Can you please help me do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AChartEngine library for the same. With this library one can draw the graphs using Intents as well.

Following link provides its implementation Sample Code:

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/06/android-chart-tutorial-achartengine.html

Hope it helps.

Thanks